# Apache Spark : How to change the port the Spark driver listens to

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark job in client mode with Yarn as the master and I am facing a particular problem. The log says that the *Yarn ApplicationMaster is waiting for the Spark driver to be reachable* and then after sometime throws an exception saying that the *Yarn ApplicationMaster failed to connect to the driver at 10.60.18.77:34332*. Now, I know that the IP is reachable but the port is not because the firewall is blocking it. Trying to get the admins to open a port is tedious. So is there a way I can make the Yarn Application listen to another port say 20002 which I know is open as opposed to 34332?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that by setting `spark.driver.port=20002`

For example in your spark-submit you could use something lik:

`$ spark-submit --master yarn-client --conf spark.driver.port=20002 ....`

Comment: Is there a way of configuring this in the SparkSession object? (I'm using PySpark)

Comment: yes there is a way, but I recommend against that. it is better to configure that in the command line. Hard coding the config inside the code will require you to have new release every time you need to change this port

Comment: config = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.driver.port', '20002'])

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. So when using PySpark, how do I set this configuration using the **command line**?

Comment: using the very same command I used in the answer, just provide .py file that contains your driver.