# ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, amazon-emr

**Scala version: 2.11.12**

**Spark version: 2.4.0**

**emr-5.23.0**

Get the following when running the below command to create an Amazon EMR cluster

```
spark-submit --class etl.SparkDataProcessor --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ETL_NAME=foo --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ETL_SPARK_MASTER=yarn --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ETL_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=123 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ETL_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=abc MY-Tool.jar
```

**Exception**

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:773)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

**How I create my spark session (where sparkMaster = yarn)**

```
lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger("etl");
    val sparkAppName = EnvConfig.ETL_NAME
    val sparkMaster = EnvConfig.ETL_SPARK_MASTER

    val sparkInstance = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName(sparkAppName)
      .master(sparkMaster)
      .getOrCreate()

    val hadoopConf = sparkInstance.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", EnvConfig.ETL_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", EnvConfig.ETL_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    logger.info("Created My SparkSession")
    logger.info(s"Spark Application Name: $sparkAppName")
    logger.info(s"Spark Master: $sparkMaster")

    sparkInstance
  }
```

UPDATE:

I determined that due to the application logic, in certain cases, we did not initialize the spark session. Because of this, it seems that when the cluster terminates, it also tries to do something with the session (perhaps close it) and is thus failing. Now that I have figured out this issue, the application runs but never actually completes. Currently, it seems to be hanging in a particular part involving spark when running in cluster mode:

```
val data: DataFrame = spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv(s"s3://$csvPath/$fileKey")
      .toDF()

20/03/16 18:38:35 INFO Client: Application report for application_1584324418613_0031 (state: RUNNING)
```

Comment: --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ETL_SPARK_MASTER=yarn this is not required instead of that use --master

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK  `EnvConfig.ETL_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `ETL_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are not getting populated due to which sparksession cant be instanciated with null or empty values . try to print and debug the values.

also reading the properties from --conf spark.xxx

should be like this example. I hope you are following this...

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf.getOption("spark. ETL_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
```

once you check that, this example way should work...

```
 /**
      * Hadoop-AWS Configuration
      */
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.host", proxyHost)
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.port", proxyPort)
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain")
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
    sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

another thing is, use

`--master yarn` or `--master local[*]` you can use instead of

```
-conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ETL_SPARK_MASTER=yarn
```

*UPDATE :*

`--conf spark.driver.port=20002` may solve this issue. where 20002 is orbitary port.. seems like its waiting for the particular port for some time and its retrying for some time and its failing with the exception you got.

I got this idea by walking through the [Sparks application master code from here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala#L515)

and comment  [This a bit hacky, but we need to wait until the spark.driver.port property has  been set by the Thread executing the user class.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/ApplicationMaster.scala#L493)

you can try this and let me know.

Further reading : [Apache Spark : How to change the port the Spark driver listens to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006317/apache-spark-how-to-change-the-port-the-spark-driver-listens-to)

Comment: The AWS keys are fine.  Even with hardcoding, the error still remains with your suggestions.  I even tried removing `.master(sparkMaster)` from within my application since I was using the --master argument to submit the application.

Comment: The `--conf spark.driver.port=20002` suggestion also did not work.

Comment: This is what I understood from code check for network code has pointer to rpc i.e. network or ports beyond this very difficult to guess and answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case (after resolving the application issues), I needed to include core AND task node types when deploying in cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest init SparkSession in start applicatioin